# How to add spaces HTML output

Tags: html

In the below code I want to create spaces when it is executed that is I want to see spaces 
**"HSC&nbsp" + txthsc.Text + "&nbspHSC" + txthscclg.Text + "**

between HSC and txthsc tag so please help..
string strBody = "" +
               "" +

```
               "<div>Your name is: <b>" + txtaddress.Text + "</b></div>" +
               "<div> your Gender:<b>"+txtgender.Text+"</b></div>"+
                "<div> your skills:<b>" + txtskills.Text + "</b></div>" +
                 "<div> your experience:<b>" + txtexp.Text+ "</b></div>" +
                  "<div> your phno:<b>" + txtphno.Text + "</b></div>" +
               "<table width=\"100%\" style=\"background-color:#cfcfcf;\"><tr><td>1st Cell body data</td><td>2nd cell body data</td></tr></table>" +

              "<table width=\"500%\" style=\"background-color:#cfcfcf;\"><tr><td>BBA<b>&nbsp" + txtbba.Text + "&nbsp</td><td>HSC<b>" + txtbbaclg.Text + "</td></tr></table>" +
              **"<table width=\"500%\" style=\"background-color:#cfcfcf;\"><tr><td>HSC<b>&nbsp" + txthsc.Text + "&nbsp</td><td>HSC<b>" + txthscclg.Text + "</td>**</tr></table>" +
              "<table width=\"500%\" style=\"background-color:#cfcfcf;\"><tr><td>SSC<b>&nbsp" + txtssc.Text + "&nbsp</td><td>HSC<b>" + txtsscclg.Text + "</td></tr></table>" +
               "Resume document generated successfully."+
           "</body>" +
           "</html>";
```

Comment: The entity is "&nbsp;", you need the semi-colon

Answer (score 3):

i think you are missing `;` from `&nbsp` - Correct entity is **`&nbsp;`**